# How to use Python autopep8 in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I installed the `autopep8` extension through `pip` in visual studio 2019, but I don't see any change in formatting at all. I tried to use the `autopep8` commands through Python interactive window in Visual Studio, but it just says that autopep8 is not a recognized command. What can I do to make it work?

P.S. — I've also tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You installed autopep8 for direct use in Python; you need to install the VS Code extension for it, too.

Click on the <kbd>Install</kbd> button in the page [Python-autopep8 for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=himanoa.Python-autopep8), or follow instructions for manual installation in it.

Comment: I use visual studio 2019 though, and I also installed autopep8 through visual studio 2019

Answer (score 0):

**Limitations:** file must be saved before running this formatting command, otherwise autopep8 will format the outdated file and overwrite your changes. You could use something like [Visual Commander](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SergeyVlasov.VisualCommander) to chain (save, then format) commands.

1. install the **autopep8** python formatting module

> `pip install pep8`
> `pip install --upgrade autopep8`

2. install the [CodeBeautifier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MariuszBrzeski.CodeBeautifier) VS 2019 extension, which enables us to run the formatter CLI from within visual studio.
3. Configure [CodeBeautifier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MariuszBrzeski.CodeBeautifier) for python projects.

> Extensions > Manobit > CodeBeautifier > Options

Inside the extension options you can add a language profile for **python.**

- Set formatter **application: {full path to autopep8 executable}**
  (path can be found at `{Python Installation Path}\Scripts\autopep8.exe`)
- Set CLI **arguments: $(FileName)** which will find the active document

4. Create a keyboard shortcut for CodeBeautifier

> Tools > Options > Enviornment > Keyboard

filter shortcuts for: **Manobit.CodeBeautifier.CurrentDocument**

Then simply assign a shortcut keys for the command. Whenever this shortcut runs the active document will be formatted with autopep8.